# ddrescue - cloning a device

Tags: linux, hard-drive, clone, disk-image, cloning

I am running the following command

```
[root@localhost ~]# ddrescue -vf /dev/sdf /dev/sdg rescue.log
```

Do I need to do anything else after that to make the drive bootable? One place said I should do a second pass with:

```
ddrescue -d -r3 /dev/sdf /dev/sdg rescue.log
```

Is that overkill?

Comment: It might make it bootable, it kinda depends on how badly it was corrupted/broken.   Personally I would try to immediately backup the data after you recovered what you where able to.  Then re-build the filesystem/environment and restore.  I don't think I would spend much effort on trying to make a usable system out of something recovered from a failing drive.  Whether you need to run it again kinda depends on what you see in the rescue.log, and if you are able to verify that the files you needed were recovered.

Comment: Yea, first thing I did was recover all the files. Now just cloning to the new drive just to avoid having to reconfigure the setup again.

Comment: What version ddrescue is that? Mine doesn't know of a -d flag.

Comment: 1.16 it was the latest version

Answer (score 1):

A second run of ddrescue with `-r3` would be necessary if and only if the first run finished with "errsize > 0B" or "errors > 0" (something that was not recovered in the first pass).

You would also be able to tell if there were any errors (needing the second run) by checking rescue.log to see if there were any blocks left in states other than `+` (finished).

But a second run would *not* be overkill.  As long as the second run was given the same `rescue.log` file produced by the first run, then the second run would finish immediately if there were no errors left over from the first run.